# How to Handle/Kill a Locked Thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I've seen many questions on how to kill a locked thread, and every answer I've seen says not to kill the thread, don't even use Thread.Abort, just use good programming practice to handle when the thread should stop.

My problem is, I'm stuck using an old 3rd party library I have no control over, and once in awhile this locks up, using pretty much 100% CPU and never letting go.  Thread.Abort does not stop this.  I can't find any way to stop this.

The best 'workaround' I've found is using a delegate and .AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10000, false);

Code will continue from this point after the timeout, but still whatever thread is running continues to run and use up all of my CPU.

How can I handle this situation?  If this 3rd party library locks up, I need a way to kill it.

Thanks for your time,
Ben

Comment: How do you call the code from this library? Did you explicitly create a new thread for this, if yes how? Piece of code will be useful.

Comment: It's not possible to just kill threads. The only thing you can kill safely is the whole process. `Thread.Abort` will only ever work while the thread is executing managed code, so for a native 3rd-party library, it's not going to help. So, separate the offending code into a new simple process that you run from your application and terminate if needed.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a general answer, make a separate process with the code that tends to lock. Kill and restart the process as necessary. With more knowledge of the exact problem you are facing, better solutions may become available.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate application domain to run an assembly that is untrusted or just doesn't work from time to time as in your case. An application domain can be unloaded at any time and it will create a border between your code and external one. Here is a small example. Let's start with the external assembly that contains incorrect code:

```
public class Processor
{
    public void Run() 
    {
        while (true) { /* ... */ }                
    }
}
```

Now we need a class that will load *BadAssembly.dll*, create an instance of *Processor* and call *Run* method in the separate thread in order not to block the main thread of your application.

```
public class Loader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }
    public bool IsFaulted  { get; private set; }

    public void LoadAndRunBadAssembly()
    {
        var ass = Assembly.LoadFrom("BadAssembly.dll");
        var c = (Processor)ass.CreateInstance("BadAssembly.Processor");

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    c.Run();
                    IsCompleted = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    IsFaulted = true;
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}
```

*IsCompleted* and *IsFaulted* properties are needed to let us know if an external code has already finished processing or not. *Loader* is derived from *MarshalByRefObject* because thanks to that its code will be executed in the separate domain created by us. And here is a code to test *Loader* class:

```
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Loader");
try
{
    //Here I assume that Loader class is in the same assembly as this code
    var loader = (Loader)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, 
        typeof (Loader).FullName);

    loader.LoadAndRunBadAssembly();

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");

    Thread.Sleep(20000); //This simulates waiting for external code

    if (loader.IsCompleted)
        Console.WriteLine("Processing has finished");
    else if (loader.IsFaulted)
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("It lasts too long");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
finally
{
    AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've just realized that in order to stop threads in a domain *AppDomain.Unload* method uses *Abort* method. It means that you may receive [CannotUnloadAppDomainException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.cannotunloadappdomainexception(v=vs.110).aspx) exception when trying to unload a domain. It will happen because it is not guaranteed that *Abort* will kill a thread immediately.

Comment: If the threads in an appdomain cannot be aborted the domain will not unload.

Comment: I run this code a few times and it worked. For example try to place Console.Writeline within the while loop of Processor.Run method and run the program. After 20s no new message will appear in console. You can also run my code in Debug and observe Modules window in Visual Studio. After 20s BadAssembly.dll will be removed from the list and it means that the application domain was unloaded. The similar exercise can be made with Threads window. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, the part of the question that says `Thread.Abort()` does not stop this, suggesting that the hang is in unmanaged code.

Comment: You can repro by writing `finally { Thread.Sleep(100000); }`.